# Rewrite URL with 1 or several query in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL with query that one of it's query maybe is not set.
Target URL:

```
domain.com/category.php
```

Query of URL:

```
1. c = any character in UTF-8 [It is required]
2. page = number [It is not required and maybe not set]
```

Now, how change URL in .htaccess:

from `domain.com/category.php?c=anyCharacter` to `domain.com/category/anyCharacter/`

and from `domain.com/category.php?c=anyCharacter&page=number` to `domain.com/category/anyCharacter/page:number/`

**UPDATE**:

I found an answer but it is not complete.

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ category.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will change URL:

from `domain.com/category/anyCharacter/` to `domain.com/category.php?c=anyCharacter`

and from `domain.com/category/anyCharacter/?page=number` to `domain.com/category.php?c=anyCharacter&page=number`

But it's not **good answer** because I don't want any user see ***Query*** in my URL.
*Please do not write my answer again.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 2 rewrite rules for this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f    
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?c=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page:(\d+)/?$ category.php?c=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: I know. I edited your answer before you but it's not set yet. thanks. It's work now.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to go from pretty URL to variables?
You could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?c=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This will translate `yourdomain.com/a/2` to `yourdomain.com?c=a&page=2`